# I can not go to bottom of my android activity

Tags: android

I can not go to the boottom of my activity. If I want to read all text or go to rating bar or button i cant. I think the problem is in xml format or something in xml file. Do you know where is the problem? I try to search why i cant scroll to the bottom of my activity, but i dont found nothing helpful

I cant not go under the red line

[image]

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".ClickedItemActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Director"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvDirector"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Genre"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDirector"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvGenre"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Summary"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvGenre"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvSummary"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:shadowRadius="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:text="Гласувай"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSummary"/>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Do u have any idea where is the problem?

Comment: Use scrollview in your layout

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your parent layout as ScrollView.
Something like this

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".ClickedItemActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Director"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvDirector"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Genre"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDirector"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvGenre"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Summary"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvGenre"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvSummary"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:shadowRadius="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:text="Гласувай"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSummary"/>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3" />


</RelativeLayout>
      
</ScrollView>
```